# clearing after a float left creates a void between two divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following part of my html

```
<div class="header">            
    <div class="header-bar">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <div class="title">Ci models database</div>
        </div>
    </div>              
    <div class="clear-both"></div>
    <ol class=breadcrumb>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">All models</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

the css(breadcrumb and active classes are bootstrap)

```
.header-bar {
    border: None;
    background-color: #66CCFF;
    min-height:30px;
}

.title {
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
}
.clear-both{
    clear:both; 
}
```

But between header-bar and breadcrumb html added a white space([see bootply](http://www.bootply.com/y9hZk3MjkB)). How can I remove this white space, since no padding and margin can be found between to divs.

Comment: The `breadcrumb` class has vertical padding built in...could that be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apostolos, the white space is coming from the `.title`class.
The bottom padding of 10px.
Zero this and the white space will go.

```
.title {
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
```

Comment: Don't get it. `.title` is inside `.pull-left`. So padding bottom should only apply to that div. I can't understand how it goes outside the `.tile`div to the `.header-bar` div

Comment: Does it answer your question, of how to remove the white space? If so mark it as answered.

Comment: @Apostolos - I'd made some effort to explain and also offer alternatives ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30780284/1249829

Comment: Gee, looks like someone jumped in here quick. Working on other questions. [Have a look at this it may help explain thing here.](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/)  It comes down to both margin and padding need something to push against.  I asked if it answered your question because, I wasn't sure from your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the calculated height of the internal `.title` div is greater than the calculated height of the container `.header-bar`. Properties like height, min-height, border, padding can directly effect heights, whereas properties like display, box-sizing and position can all indirectly effect height.

The result is the internal `.title` div pushes down the next div in the flow by 10px.

CSS has no rules that say a div must contain it's children in height and stop them from effecting other divs, [even when height is directly defined](http://www.bootply.com/jxSujD69ql). We need to tell it exactly how it should behave when things are rendered.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. http://www.bootply.com/Qa1ME2M2uk - use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent. [Overflow is a css property](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) which is used how to control what happens when child elements are larger than their parents. It's worth noting that depending on other properties overflow won't necessarily render itself in a way that disrupts layout.
2. http://www.bootply.com/ssq3EAzeyk - set explicit heights to take strict control over the dimensions of the elements. This might be the best option for a header bar.
3. http://www.bootply.com/yeodYRLLJk - set a greater min-height on the parent, one which will definitely contain the child. This is useful if your padding is for alignment purposes - setting `min-height: 40px;` in the example does this.
4. http://www.bootply.com/GznfJxUWUF - remove the padding that is making the element calculate as taller (as mentioned in another answer).

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add a `float: left` to both parent containers (`.header-bar` and `breadcrumb`) otherwise the clear won't affect anything. furthermore you will have to give both containers `width: 100%`

```
.header-bar {
    border: None;
    background-color: #66CCFF;
    min-height:30px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.title {
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
}
.clear-both{
    clear:both; 
}
```